# Combined analytics

Tags: analytics

I have got olap cube on ssas which has all operational history data
I need a front end toll which can not only show data from cube but also sources like web crawl scribe blogs Facebook etc.
Can I leverage any open source software for building required reports which can be run in real time
Have got OBIEE but need a platform which can help devise such reports through a search screen on wrbsitw with parameter enters by user